# Vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ belong to vector space $\mathbb{Z}^{3}_{7}$ What's dimension of the subspace $U_7$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, elementary-number-theory, vector-spaces, vectors

> $v_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\  3\\  5 \end{pmatrix} , v_2=\begin{pmatrix}
> 4\\  5\\  6 \end{pmatrix}, v_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 6\\  4\\  2
> \end{pmatrix}$ are vectors of the vector space $\mathbb{Z}^{3}_{7}$,
>   over the field $\mathbb{Z}_{7}$. What's the dimension of $U_{7}=
> \text{span}\left\{v_1,v_2,v_3\right\}$?

I think the elements of all vectors are alright because they are in $\mathbb{Z}_{7}= \left\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\right\}$, if that is understood correctly at all by me **(?)**

Now I form the vectors to a matrix: $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 4 & 6\\ 
3 & 5 & 4\\ 
5 & 6 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$ and transpose it: $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 & 5\\ 
4 & 5 & 6\\ 
6 & 4 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$

Multiply first line with $4$:

$\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 12 & 20\\ 
4 & 5 & 6\\ 
6 & 4 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$

But $12$ and $20 \notin \mathbb{Z}_{7}$. So we have to do $12 \text{ mod } 7= 5$ and $20 \text{ mod } 7= 6$

Insert that in the matrix: $\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 5 & 6\\ 
4 & 5 & 6\\ 
6 & 4 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$

Now subtract first line second line, we get: $\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 5 & 6\\ 
0 & 0 & 0\\ 
6 & 4 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$

And thus the dimension of $U_{7}=
\text{span}\left\{v_1,v_2,v_3\right\}$ is $2$?

Another question, I had to check at the beginning if the vectors are linearly independent **?**

Comment: Without checking deeply it looks fine...but rather messy and without a clear, fixed method: why won't you simply *reduce* the original matrix by means of elementary (Gauss) operations? That's all we need: at the end, the number of non-all-zero rows is the dimension of the space spanned by the rows. Period. What you did seems to have worked *by chance* in this very particular case. Reduction works **always**

Comment: @DonAntonio Does that mean the transposition is completely useless? Is it also not  required if I wanted know basis / image?

Comment: @cn Indeed. Transposition only makes you waste time... **unless** it is a requirement from your instructor, of course. Now, for **a** basis of the kernel of a given matrix: you have to do exactly as above: rows, reduction...and what is left is a basis for the kernel. For the image **though** you need to work with the *columns*...but you then can indeed take the transpose, reduce again and etc., and what is left **in  rows** is a basis for the image.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you very much! :))

Comment: @cn My pleasure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could have simply reduced the matrix by rows (with rows = the given vectors):

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&3&5\\
4&5&6\\
6&4&2\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_2-4R_1,\,R_3-6R_1}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1&3&5\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\implies$$

The second and third vectors are linearly dependent on the first one , and in fact:

$$\begin{pmatrix}4\\5\\6\end{pmatrix}=4\begin{pmatrix}1\\3\\5\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}6\\4\\2\end{pmatrix}=6\begin{pmatrix}1\\3\\5\end{pmatrix}$$

and thus the dimension of the span of these three vectors over $\;\Bbb F_7\cong\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z\;$ is one .

Keeping track of which vector is represented by what row (in case we interchange some of them) we can say, at the end of the row reduction,  *exactly* which ones are lin. dependent on which ones, and we can even write down exactly what is the linear dependency. I think that by far this is the best method.